# What is the Predicted columns in spotfire and how it works?

Tags: spotfire

As I am not sure about predicted columns which are used in Spotfire 6.0.Could you please help me on this.

Than k you in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

The [free jumpstart video](http://learn.spotfire.tibco.com/course/view.php?id=85) available from TIBCO covers and demonstrate on [Lesson 3](http://learn.spotfire.tibco.com/mod/url/view.php?id=3804) how these computational tools work by the machines that make our civilization run, from the people whose ingenuity created them.